# can not read value from dynamically create control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am stuck with following issue.I've google a lot and try every method but could not solve issue

I am creating control dynamically and after that reading value from dynamically created control

but every time I get error "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object" means I am not able to locate the control even if it available on page.

here is my code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {



TextBox txt = new TextBox();
   txt.ID = "myText";
   txt.ViewStateMode = System.Web.UI.ViewStateMode.Enabled;
   Panel1.Controls.Add(txt);

 }

 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

       TextBox txt = Panel1.FindControl("myText") as TextBox;

       Response.Write(txt.Text);

 }
```

Here is aspx page code :

```
<div>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

   <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>

   <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button2_Click"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you create the control when `Button1` is clicked, and then try and access it when `Button2` is clicked. Dynamic controls must be created on **every post back** because that state is not maintained. Instead of **just** building the control in `Button1` click, set a flag in `Session` so you know to rebuild it on `Load` too. So, in `Button1_Click`, at the ***very end of the method***, add this line:

```
Session["BuildMyText"] = true;
```

and then in `Page_Load`:

```
if (Session["BuildMyText"] != null && (bool)Session["BuildMyText"])
{
    // build the text box here too
}
```

and then finally, wrap the construction of the text box in the `Button1_Click` like this:

```
if (Session["BuildMyText"] != null && (bool)Session["BuildMyText"])
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate the control as below:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       TextBox txt = new TextBox();  //add this line
       TextBox txt = Panel1.FindControl("myText") as TextBox;

       Response.Write(txt.Text);

     }
```

Comment: Ubaid . this is not possible

Comment: you are right @Sandy...  :) Now I know why, textbox is out of scope